# Perforce to Github with multiple branches migration with correct revision

Tags: github, migration, perforce

I successfully brought Perforce depot to Git with all the history and branches. but when I check the revision graph of the git repo, all the commits are broken , one points to master branch and other commits point to other branches after migration. Really appreciate if someone can provide some help.
here is my perforce depot layout
     //depot/client/main
     //depot/client/main/releases/branch 1  (branch 1 was created from main
     //depot/client/main/releases/branch 2  (branch 2 was created from 
     branch1)

```
 p4 integrate //depot/client/main //depot/client/releases/branch 1
 p4 integrate //depot/client/branch 1 //depot/client/releases/branch 2
```

here is the git branch mapping 
     git config --add git-p4.branchList main:branch1
     git config --add git-p4.branchList releases/branch1:releases/branch2

command used for migration
     git p4 clone //depot/client/...@all --detect-branches --verbose

Comment: here is the git branch mapping 
git config --add git-p4.branchList main:branch1
git config --add git-p4.branchList releases/branch1:releases/branch2

Comment: here is the git branch mapping 
     git config --add git-p4.branchList main:branch1
     git config --add git-p4.branchList releases/branch1:releases/branch2